# Force all entity relations to be LAZY by default with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, metadata, lazy-loading

I know I can change the `fetch` on entities to be `FetchType.LAZY` with annotation, but I want a solution, that isn't prone to forgetting.

Is there a way to force **all** relations of entities to be always `FetchType.LAZY`?

For example, with Doctrine 2 ORM there is an event, that is invoked when metadata is loaded and I can hook into that event and reconfigure the metadata objects of the entities programmatically, right after they've been parsed.

Thank you